# Get MessageDigest instance digest and block sizes?

Tags: java, hash, message-digest

How to get the digest size and the block size of a message digest algorithm based on its MessageDigest instance?

Comment: [`getDigestLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/MessageDigest.html#getDigestLength()). The notion of block size has no relevance to hash functions, they accept inputs of any size and return a fixed size output.

Comment: I need the block size to implement an algorithm. SHA-1, MD-5, and other such algorithms do have a block size (both 512 bits) and I need to get it programmatically.

Comment: The block size is an internal feature of the hash function and, like many other internal features, there is no API method to retrieve that information. It's hard to imagine any programmatic use for that information, a hash function is not a block cipher.

Comment: President James is correct.